# Need help using vba to select rows with dynamic data from dynamic sheets and consolidate in a new sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am New to VBA and i dont know anything in it. So the problem is that i have a excel with dynamic sheets and data. The datas in all the sheets will be in similar format. The number of data in all the sheet will be changing and the sheets to. so could anyone help me with that. I would like be in a great deal of debt to you if you help me out.

Code what i did so for

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Add a new summary worksheet.
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            ' Specify the range to place the data.
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:b60")

            ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
            ' worksheet to copy all the data.
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.count > DestSh.Rows.count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                   "summary worksheet to place the data."
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            ' This statement copies values and formats from each
            ' worksheet.
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            ' Optional: This statement will copy the sheet
            ' name in the H column.
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you need exactly?

Comment: i will give the document and the format i need it to be. Can you develop the  code to gather the data from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow first! We're a QA community that loves to help people. That being said, we would appreciate it if you could show a little effort and try to code a solution to your problem before you ask.

Comment: For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
      Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:b60")
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

Comment: Now this code takes specified range. But i need it to pick up dynamic range. Can u Help?

Comment: Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:b60")

Comment: How do i make this statement copy dynamic or all data in it

Comment: you want it to get the last row of data instead of manually putting 60?

Comment: Yes Excatly. That and i have a list of column containg names which i would like to copy into rows in the same output sheet. all are which havin dynamic data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, to set a range dynamically, you can do this way:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Range
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Range("A1:b" & LastRow)
```

`LastRow` is a long which stores in the last data row in column `a`. Just make sure to put the column letter which you're sure it always has data to make this work properly.

**Explanation:**

1. `Dim lastrow as long`: This tells VBA to create a long datatype (longs are 4 bytes-sized datatypes that range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647). variable called `lastrow`.
2. `Dim r As Range`: Tells VBA to create a range object. Hopefully, you know what a range is.
3. `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row`. We can look at this like follow:

   `Cells(Rows.count,"a")` will return a range object delimited by the row number `rows.count`(the entire count of rows in the sheet) and the column `a`.

   `.End(xlup)` is a property of the above range. It will return another range object however this time, it is range of non-empty cells. `Xlup` is the argument of this property and it basically means that the property is going to read cells from below and upwards hence the *up* direction. The means it will stop at the first cell that contains data from below.
4. The above property has returned an range object. the `.Row` property will return the actual number of rows in that object.
5. `LastRow` will receive that number now.
6. `Set r = range("A1:B" & lastrow)` is telling vba to set the value of the r object to a range object from ranges from `"A1"` to `"B"&lastrow"`.

   Now you have a dynamic range called r.

Comment: You need to clean your code first before that trying that code. I suggest that you try it on a new spreadsheet to see it work.

Comment: can you make changes in the code and send it to me so that i can understand it